# Передача значения из формы в js

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с этой проблемой в браузере Mozilla FF, при селект передает значение только первого option

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function test()
    {
     var a = document.getElementById("sel").value;
     alert(a);  
    }
    </script>
 <form>
    <select name="sel" id="sel" class="styled" onChange="test();">';
    <option value="1">1</option>   
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

В итоге чтобы я не выбрал выдает значение 1, такая ерунда получается только в мозиле

Answer (score 1):

Если ваш JS находиться в конце html-кода, перед закрывающим тегом body или, по крайней мере, после той самой формы, то всё работает нормально. Хотя, я бы отделил JS от HTML

**HTML**

```
<select name="sel" id="sel" class="styled">'
    <option value="1">1</option>   
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
var sel = document.getElementById("sel");
sel.onchange = function(){
    alert(this.value);
};
```

Пример [тутачки](http://jsfiddle.net/mbXzM/)

Comment: Очень странно, но мой пример в той песочнице тоже работает, а вот на сайте через FF почему-то передается только одно значение

Comment: Что я вам могу сказать? Ищите баги в вашем коде.